# The site is not valid. The Pages document libaray is missing

Tags: sharepoint-server, pages

I'm facing this issues when i'm creating pages under a site collection, sometimes even in subsites I'm not able to create pages.[image]

How can this be corrected?

Comment: Is publishing feature activated ?

Comment: Have you created sites based on a template that had publishing feature activated?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue it is required to update the value of the **__PagesListId** property value to match the ID of the Pages library.

This can be done (e.g.) through the following Powershell script:

```
$web = get-spweb http://site-collection/path-to-affected-site
$correctId = $web.Lists["Pages"].ID
$web.AllProperties["__PagesListId"] = $correctId.ToString()
$web.Update()
```

Comment: do we need to run for each subsite or need to run in root site ?? i have around 100 subsite ..

Comment: Using this You need to run on each subsite...:(

Comment: omg! is there any script to run in all subsites in single shot???

Comment: First of all try to activate - deactivate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature and check Pages library and then after activate - deactivate "SharePoint Server Publishing" (site feature).